# Update localstorage using jquery

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have local storage data i.e, key => MOHAN and value => `<table><p>hjjhjh</p></table>` and I want to replace the `<p>` with null.
How to achieve this?

Below is code,

```
var string = localStorage.getItem("MOHAN");
var new_string = remove.replace('<p>','')
localStorage.setItem("MOHAN",new_string);
```

Comment: Your code fails at every line. Is that even your code? Why do you want to involve jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code snippet,

```js
 var string = '<table><p>hjjhjh</p></table>';
 var new_string = string.replace(/<p>/g,'')
 new_string = new_string.replace(/<\/p>/g,'');
 console.log( new_string);
 localStorage.setItem("MOHAN", new_string);
```